# Toggle after dragging an element still affects other elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to build some information bars that are fixed to bottom left and can be toggled 
by the user to see there content.

Each div can be dragged around the screen and when double clicking it he will return to 
the original position.

So far its working fine, my problem is that after dragging div2 or div3 (see code in the fiddle)
and clicking the toggle trigger it affects the other divs that was above in the original position.

I want the divs to be affected by the toggle only when he is in the left corner but i want to disable this movement after dragging it out of the list.

I tried to addClass after dragging, that sets a higher z-index value - and removing it when double click but it didn't worked, for some reason it affected all the divs.

Any ideas?

here is a sample in jsfiddle: [my sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/y9Y8s/)

CSS:

```
#container
{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:15;
}
.bardiv
{
    width:300px;
    background-color:orange;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
<div id='1' class='bardiv'>drag / double click me - div 1 / <a class ='toggleme' href='#'>toggle </a>
    <div class='conn'>content</div>
</div>
<div id='2' class='bardiv'>drag / double click me - div 2 /<a class ='toggleme' href='#'>toggle </a>
    <div class='conn'>content</div>
</div>
<div id='3' class='bardiv'>drag / double click me - div 3 /<a class ='toggleme' href='#'>toggle   </a>
    <div class='conn'>content</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.conn').hide();

$('.toggleme').click(function() {
$(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast');
});

$( ".bardiv" ).draggable({ opacity: 0.7, cursor: 'move', cancel: '.toggleme' });

$( ".bardiv" ).dblclick(function () { 
    $(this).animate({ left: 0, top: 0 }, "slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't 100% sure what you meant but I think this might fix the issue.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y9Y8s/2/

```
$('.conn').hide();

$('#container').css('min-height', $('#container').height());

$('.toggleme').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle('fast');
});

$( ".bardiv" ).draggable({
    opacity: 0.7,
    cursor: 'move',
    cancel: '.toggleme',
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css('position', 'absolute');
    }
});

$( ".bardiv" ).dblclick(function () { 
    $(this).animate({ left: 0, top: 0 }, "slow");
    $(this).css('position', 'relative');
 });
```

Comment: nice solution - but why does a white space remains after dragging out the div?

Comment: The whitespace remains because the container has a minimum height set by jQuery.  The issue is that if you do not set a min-height and a draggable div is dragged outside of the container, the position is then set as absolute and the container reduces it's height by the height of the element that was set to position absolute.  

jsFiddle to show behavior: http://jsfiddle.net/y9Y8s/3/

If you watch closely, you can see the divs jump as each element is dragged out of the container.